# Error when trying to create a public form using a profile with a Grant field

Tags: wordpress, profile, grant

I am trying to create a publicly accessible grant application page using a CiviCRM profile with form fields for Grant record information.

To test this, I created a profile with only one Grant-record field in it.

When I then create a Wordpress post using the shortcode for the profile, it gives this error: "Profile search, view and edit are not supported for Profiles which include fields for more than one record type."

If I change the form to have just one field of some other type of field (with no Grant field), for example, Individual - Birth Date, then it works just fine.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

You'll need the [Grant Application Pages](https://civicrm.org/extensions/grant-application-pages) extension to do what you want.  I believe [Caldera Forms CiviCRM](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf-civicrm/)  will also do the trick, and give you some more flexibility to boot - but I'll admit I haven't tried that approach.